# hover on everything but selected text

Tags: html, css, hover

I just want to use css and html to change the colour of non selected text.

Text on same line
Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 and Option 4.

Hover on option 1 to make Option 2,3,4 in grey.

Looked at this: [Hover on "everything but" aka "spotlight" effect: how to make smooth & easy hover transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377379/hover-on-everything-but-aka-spotlight-effect-how-to-make-smooth-easy-hove)

I want text to be on the same line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Always mention it while questioning something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code from the other thread and use span or display:inline-block to get the text to be on the same line.

Comment: Where should I add span/ inline-block?
HTML
<header>
  <nav><a href="">Option 1</a></nav>
  <nav><a href="">Option 2</a></nav>
  <nav><a href="">Option 3</a></nav>
  <nav><a href="">Option 4</a></nav>
</header>

CSS

nav a {
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header:hover nav:not(:hover) a { 
  color: lightgrey;
}

Comment: Like this: https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/XWKbagM